# An elementary special case of Brunn Minkowski inequality

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with a point $O$ in the interior and points $P,Q,R,S$ on the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$ respectively such that $APOS\text{ and }CROQ$ are parallelograms. Prove that $$\sqrt{S_{BQOP}}+\sqrt{S_{DSOR}}\le \sqrt{S_{ABCD}}.$$

This is obvious with Brunn Minkowski but I'd like to see an elementary solution, since this problem was posed in St Petersburg math circle.

My idea: square both sides gives

$$S_{APOS}+S_{CROQ}\ge 2\sqrt{S_{BQOP}\cdot S_{DSOR}}.$$

Then we might be able to prove this by some evaluation between the area of the parallelograms and the quadrilaterals, then use AM GM. This might work because I think it is some what similar to the proof of Brunn Minkowski in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I'll wait a bounty!

Comment: This is ISL 1995 G7: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h67985p399545